# How to check multiple file extension with using javascript in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm trying to put a file upload button and this button provides to upload video files with extension mp4,avi,swf so how can I check these multiple extension with javascript?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <br />
        <p><input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="23"/></p><br />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>        
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var selectedFile = $('#file').val();
        var matches = selectedFile.match(/\.(xlsx?)$/i);
        if (matches == null) {
            alert('please select an Excel file');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have some of regular expressions to validate file upload.

Regular expression to validate file formats for .mp3 or .MP3 or .mpeg or .MPEG or m3u or M3U

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.mp3|.MP3|.mpeg|.MPEG|.m3u|.M3U)$/;
```

Regular expression to validate file formats for .doc or .docx

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.doc|.docx|.DOC|.DOCX)$/;
```

Regular expression to validate file formats for .txt or .TXT

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.txt|.TXT)$/;
```

Regular expression to validate file formats for .jpeg or .JPEG or .gif or .GIF or .png or .PNG

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF| .png|.PNG)$/;
```

Using this you can change based upon your requirements...

```
 var myRegExp = /[a-zA-z]$/;
    if(myRegExp.test("testing the string"))
    {
      // Success
    }
    else
    {
      // Fail
    }
```

hope this helps :D ....

Comment: Yes it is usefull reqular expression but I need with javascript. Not ask me why you have to use javascript because of my client wants :))

Comment: You can refer the answer I Changed :D